# Deepcopy with no Import Copy

Tags: python, copy, deep-copy

I want to deepcopy a list without the use of copy.deepcopy().

In this case:

```
def gen_parc():
    return [1,0,0] # Parc has to be generated this way.

def parc_state_update(parc):
    parc[1] = 1
    return parc

def copy_parc(parc):
    return ?
```

How can I make a deepcopy of the parc after I run it thru the state update function?

Comment: Is the list always just going to be a list of ints?

Comment: yes, it will always be either 1's or 0's.

Comment: Then you don't need a deep copy. A shallow copy is fine.